# Restrict Github access to a single repository in ssh and https URL

Tags: git, github, ssh, https

I want to deploy software on a machine for a customer but have multiple private repositories and also belong to multiple organizations.

I do not want to give the customer access to all the organizations of which I am a member. All I want to do is to deploy the code and allow the customer to update it periodically.

There is a similar question here: Restrict Github API access to only one repository of a user

However, I cannot see a way of restricting the SSH access to a single repository in Github.

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

Does anyone know how I can allow access to a single private repository only on a remote PC?

Comment: SSH keys are managed per accounts and not repositories, what you could do is create projects and add the repository that belongs to that project, also add the customer's GitHub account to that project for them to be able to have access to it, hope it helps.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to restrict Git access to a single repository, then you can use an [SSH deploy key](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys), which may be either read only or read-write.  They're designed for exactly this case.  GitHub doesn't currently provide a way to limit access to a single repository based on HTTP credentials.

Note that deploy keys must be unique; that is, a single deploy key must be a different key than is used for any user or for any other repository.

You could also add the customer as a collaborator on that single repo, in which case they'd be able to access that repo, but not anything else.

Comment: Any options if you do not have access to the repo settings (working as a collaborator)?

Comment: I don't believe there's a way for collaborators to create such credentials, no.

Answer (score 2):

Are you giving the customer access to your account? That seems to be how someone can access your private repositories.

You can have the customer create a git account, add them as a collaborator to your private repository and add the ssh key of the machine to their account.
The customer then can use their account to access your repository. I believe that way they will have access to their repository, but not your other repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fine-grained personal access tokens to access single repository: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#fine-grained-personal-access-tokens